# Why $s/(1-s) = 1$ at $s=1$ in bode plot?

Tags: graphing-functions

Wolfram [plot of $\frac{s}{1-s}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20of%20s/%281-s%29) is $\pm\infty$ at $s=1$. But, [bode plot of $\frac{s}{1-s}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=bode%20%20plot%20of%20s/%281-s%29) results in $1$ at $s=1$. Obviously, this is wrong. Why?

Comment: You could look at what a [bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) is.

Comment: @PeterShor I think the asker's question is valid. Even from reading the wiki article, it's not entirely clear what's happening here if you're new to Bode plots and frequency domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x-axis in the Bode plot isn't $s$, but $\omega$. Remember that $s=j\omega$, so what you're seeing in the Bode plot is as follows:

$$20\log|H(j1)|=20\log|\frac{j1}{1-j1}|=20\log|\frac{j(1+j)}{2}|$$

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I see that I can choose W=1 and get one plot or choose s=1 and, then, get w=-i and another plot. Which one should I choose? Can I understand the difference between Laplace and Fourier based on that?

Comment: @Val Most likely $\omega=1$ will prove the most useful. See, the difference between $s$ and $j\omega$ is $s$ is a complex number, whereas $j\omega$ is only an imaginary number. The real component of $s$ is what is known as the damping frequency, whereas the imaginary part is the frequency that most of us are familiar with: the periodicity. The chances are, if you're looking at a Bode plot, you're more interested in the latter.